# What's a good file format to use for storing player saved files?

Tags: java, file-format

I'm making a game in Java, and I need a good file format to store the player's saved data.

Any suggestions?

Feel free to give examples in code if you want.

EDIT: This is a server-client game, so the saved data will be on the server's machine. Also, I don't want to use Serialization.

Comment: What would be a typical size of the data? Does it need to be human readable?

Comment: What about some requirements...  How much data are we talking?  Are there a lot of bit streams (Images, binary files, etc)?  Is portability a concern?

Comment: I don't want it human readable, and a typical size for a single player save would be under 10Kb.

Comment: then you would want sqlite. It can be easily accessed if someone had a sqlite client but if you name the file data.dat or something instead of data.sqlite3 then they won't automatically assume that is what you are trying to do. Also you md5 hash all the data before saving it the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML

let's you save any data structure you may have in a standard format and you won't need to write your own parser/writer for it

if you need the files to be "secured" from gamers changing their scores/progress/... (not sure where the files are stored? or whether this matters?) you could pass the XML through an encryption algorithm or encrypt the data elements before putting them into the XML

Answer (score 3):

All of the answers so far seem to be about XML, which isn't a bad format, but there are other options you might find useful, which should make your startup times faster:

[Json](http://www.json.org/java/): Common and has been around longer than my next two suggestions.

[Thrift](http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/): What Facebook uses. Should be faster than Json, supported by less languages.

[Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/javatutorial.html): Used by Google. Probably the fastest, and also easy to extend.

Or just make your classes support [Serializable](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/).

Comment: +1 All of those are good ideas, especially making your class serializable.

Answer (score 2):

If as you say, the information will be saved on the server it should definitely be in a database.  The typical game protocol is store the user information in a database - pull it into memory when they login, with lazy updates to the db for changes to the object in memory (keeps game performance high) as they play the game and update their "in memory" user game state object.

Don't limit the scalability of your game by starting with file based storage just because it might be slightly easier.

Comment: You know, now that you put it that way - you're right. A database would be more proper as it's a base of data (the saved files). Hmm.

Answer (score 1):

Since its your game, you could define a file format yourself. For saving game's state directly serializing and storing will do. As for the players saved data (which could be his level progress, game score etc) you could use XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Game>
<player  id="01d">
     <name>
             John
      </name>
      <skill>
        Rookie
      </skill>
      <score>
       122
      </score>      
</player>
</Game>
```

Ofcourse you could encrypt it to make it hack-proof

Comment: Encrypting probably wouldn't do any good, since you'd need to have the key available somewhere the user can read it.